# Python - how to handle a dictionary with spaces

Tags: python, list, dictionary, whitespace

I have a list contains a dictionary as below:

```
[{'DeltaG': -14.36, 'BasePairs': 8, 'Dimer': "5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA\n                                           :   |||||||| :                                     \n3'                                      TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG"}
```

and the `['Dimer']` looks like this:

```
5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA
                                           :   |||||||| :                                     
3'                                      TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG
```

I want to filter accept or ignore dictionaries if  `|` character in the `Dimer` is not under the `N` (there is only one N at the end of the upper string and the position is always consistent).

I tried this solution and it works if there is no space before the upper sequence:

```
for i in results:
    if i['Dimer'][107] != '|':
        print(i)
```

My problem is that sometimes there are spaces before the upper string (as below) then the position `107` (i['Dimer'][107] != '|') gets incorrect. Can anyone help me with this?

#this is just a dummy example to show the structure:

```
5'      TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA
                                           :   |||||||| :                                     
3'                                      TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
d = [
    {
        "DeltaG": -14.36,
        "BasePairs": 8,
        "Dimer": "5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA\n                                           :   |||||||| :                                     \n3'                                      TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG",
    }
]

from itertools import zip_longest

# control print:
print(d[0]["Dimer"])
print()
print("-" * 80)
print()

for l1, l2, l3 in zip_longest(*d[0]["Dimer"].split("\n")):
    if l1 == "N" and l2 == "|" and l3 in "TCGA":
        print('Character | under the "N": ', l1, l3)
        break
else:
    print('No character | under the "N"')
```

Prints:

```
5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA
                                           :   |||||||| :                                     
3'                                      TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Character | under the "N":  N G
```

---

Or: If there's only just one `"N"`:

```
l1, l2, l3 = d[0]["Dimer"].split("\n")

i = l1.index("N") if "N" in l1 else None
ch2 = l2[i] if i < len(l2) else None
ch3 = l3[i] if i < len(l3) else None

if not i is None and ch2 == "|" and ch3 in "TCGA":
    print('Character | under the "N": ', ch3)
```

Prints:

```
Character | under the "N":  G
```

---

EDIT: To check multiple items:

```
lst = [
    {
        "DeltaG": -14.36,
        "BasePairs": 8,
        "Dimer": "5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA\n                                           :   |||||||| :                                     \n3'                                      TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG",
    },
    {
        "DeltaG": -12.99,
        "BasePairs": 6,
        "Dimer": "5'                TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA\n                       ::                   :    |||||| :: :    :       \n3' TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAG",
    },
]


def is_pipe_under_N(item):
    l1, l2, l3 = item["Dimer"].split("\n")

    i = l1.index("N") if "N" in l1 else None
    ch2 = l2[i] if i < len(l2) else None
    ch3 = l3[i] if i < len(l3) else None

    return not i is None and ch2 == "|" and ch3 in "TCGA"


for item in lst:
    if not is_pipe_under_N(item):
        print(item["DeltaG"])
        break
```

Prints:

```
-12.99
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrej for your help - my list has multiple of these types of dictionaries and in the end, what I want to do is to get the deltaG value for the first pair if there is no ```|``` under ```N```.

Comment: ```[{'DeltaG': -14.36, 'BasePairs': 8, 'Dimer': "5' TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA\n                                           :   |||||||| :                                     \n3'                                      TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAGGGTGTATTAGAG"}, {'DeltaG': -12.99, 'BasePairs': 6, 'Dimer': "5'                TCAGATGTGTATAAGAGACAGGTGTAATCGTTCCGCTTGAATGTGANGCAAGAA\n                       ::                   :    |||||| :: :    :       \n3' TAGTCACCTGCGTTCCTGACACTAGCGAGACAGAGAATATGTGTAGAGGCGAGCTAAGGTACTTGAAAG"}]```

Comment: so based on the list below the script should print DeltaG of -12.99 since there is no ```|``` under N for the second pair.

Comment: I understand how you code works but I could not integrate with my code below: in my code ```results``` is the same as ```d``` you used.

Comment: ```for i in results:
    deltaG = float(i["DeltaG"])
        if deltaG > max_deltaG:
            max_deltaG = deltaG
        if deltaG < min_deltaG:
            min_deltaG = deltaG

print(min_deltaG, max_deltaG)```